# Expressing integers as sums and differences of distinct powers of 3

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let:

A = { 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729 }

B = { 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729 }

C = some combination of A ($7$ Choose $k$ where $k= 0$ to $7$)

D = some combination of B ($7$ choose $k$ where $k= 0$ to $7$)

G = {1 to 1066}

So,

$$
\forall  x \in G \rightarrow x = sum(C) - sum(D)
$$

ie. All numbers in G can be represented from summing some combination from A, minus the sum of some combination from B.

How would you prove that this is true in paper? I mean, I have tested it and `sum(C) - sum(D)` does have a solution for all numbers in G. Other than doing what I did (actually writing the code to solve it), how else would I explain that this is true?

Comment: Look up Base 3 expansion. That said, this is not really on topic for MathOverflow, see http://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic

Comment: You may find [this article on balanced ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary) representation interesting.

Answer (score 2):

First notice that the sum of the elements of $A$ is $1093$; I claim that we can actually represent every integer from $-1093$ through $1093$ in the desired form, and therefore certainly every integer in $G$.

For $k=0,1,\ldots,6$ let $e_k$ be $-1$, $0$, or $1$, and let

$$f(e_0,e_1,\ldots,e_6)=\sum_{k=0}^63^ke_k=e_0+3e_1+9e_2+27e_3+81e_4+243e_5+729e_6\;.$$

If $E_A=\{k:e_k=1\}$, then $\sum_{k\in E_A}3^ke_k=\sum_{k\in E_A}3^k$ is a sum of members of $A$. Similarly, if $E_B=\{k:e_k=-1\}$, then $\sum_{k\in E_B}3^k=-\sum_{k\in E_B}3^k(-e_k)$ is a sum of members of $B$. Moreover, $$f(e_0,\ldots,e_6)=\sum_{k\in E_A}3^k-\sum_{k\in E_B}3^k$$ is a sum of members of $A$ minus a sum of members of $B$. Thus, every integer of the form $f(e_0,\ldots,e_6)$ for some choice of $e_k\in\{-1,0,1\}$ for $k=0,\dots,6$ can be expressed as such a difference, and we need only show that every integer from $-1093$ through $1093$ is such an $f(e_0,\ldots,e_6)$.

A few examples may be helpful here: you can check that

$$\begin{align*}
&f(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)=1093\;,\\
&f(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)=-1093\;,\\
&f(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)=0\;,\\
&f(0,-1,1,0,0,0,0)=6\;,\text{ and}\\
&f(1,1,-1,0,-1,0,0)=-86\;.
\end{align*}$$

Since each of $e_0,e_1,\ldots,e_6$ can be chosen in $3$ ways, there are $3^7=2187$ possible inputs to the function $f$. And $2187=2\cdot1093+1$, which is exactly the number of integers from $-1093$ through $1093$: $1093$ positive integers, $1093$ negative integers, and zero. It’s clear that $-1093$ and $1093$ are respectively the smallest and largest numbers in the range of $f$, so we’re done if we can show that $f$ takes on $2187$ different values, i.e., that it it injective (one-to-one).

Suppose that $f(e_0,\ldots,e_6)=f(e_0',\ldots,e_6')$, where each $e_k$ and $e_k'$ is $-1$, $0$, or $1$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
0&=f(e_0,\ldots,e_6)-f(e_0',\ldots,e_6')\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^63^ke_k-\sum_{k=0}^63^ke_k'\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^63^k(e_k-e_k')\;,
\end{align*}$$

where each $e_k-e_k'$ is $0$, $\pm 1$, or $\pm 2$. We’d like to show that all of them are $0$, since that would mean that $e_k=e_k'$ for $k=0,\ldots,6$. If not, let $m$ be the largest $k$ such that $e_k-e_k'\ne 0$. I’ll assume that $e_k-e_k'>0$; the argument if $e_k-e_k'<0$ is very similar. Then

$$\begin{align*}
f(e_0,\ldots,e_6)-f(e_0',\ldots,e_6')&=(e_0-e_0')+3(e_1-e_1')+3^2(e_2-e_2')+\ldots+3^m(e_m-e_m')\\
&\ge(e_0-e_0')+3(e_1-e_1')+3^2(e_2-e_2')+\ldots+3^m\\
&\ge(-2)+3(-2)+3^2(-2)+\ldots+3^{m-1}(-2)+3^m\\
&=3^m-2\left(1+3+3^2+\ldots+3^{m-1}\right)\\
&=3^m-2\left(\frac{3^m-1}{3-1}\right)\\
&=3^m-(3^m-1)\\
&=1\;,
\end{align*}$$

contradicting the hypothesis that $f(e_0,\ldots,e_6)=f(e_0',\ldots,e_6')$. Thus, it must be the case that $e_k=e_k'$ for $k=0,\ldots,6$ and hence that $f$ is injective: each of the $2187$ possible inputs produces a different output. And since the outputs are integers between $-1093$ and $1093$ inclusive, and there are exactly $2187$ integers in this range, each of those integers must be an output of $f$ and therefore representable as a sum from $A$ minus a sum from $B$.

For more on such representations of integers, you could look at the Wikipedia article on [*balanced ternary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary) representation of real numbers; a web search on that term will turn up more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The reference on balanced ternary notation may do the job. Here is a hands on way.

With only the number $1$ in each set we can do $\{0,1\}$ Note that $0=1-1$ and we get up to $1=\frac{3-1}{2}$.

With the numbers $1,3$ in each set we can do $\{0,1\}$ and $3-\{0,1\}=\{2,3\}$ and $3+\{0,1\}=\{3,4\}$ which takes us up to $4=\frac {9-1}{2}$

[Note: the extra numbers at this stage are the ones which actually use the $3$, and we go negative if we subtract the $3$ - a similar comment applies at each additional stage]

With the numbers $1,3,9$ we can do $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $9-\{0,1,2,3,4\}=\{5,6,7,8,9\}$ and $9+\{0,1,2,3,4\}=\{9,10,11,12,13\}$. This takes us up to $13=\frac{27-1}2$.

The pattern is now obvious, and it is not difficult to prove.